# Reverse optimum attribute of meter tag HTML 5

Tags: html

Hoping somebody can help, I am using the HTML5 meter tag however for my desired purpose it looks odd having the 'optimum' attribute work the way it does i.e red when low, green when high

It will represent a bin level, therefore when its high i would like it to show red and green when low.

Is there anyway to reverse the functionality of the optimum attribute when assigned to the meter tag?

Thanks, Will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you're looking for, but I created the following for you which is green until it is above the `high` value, at which it turns red

```
/* HTML */
<meter min="0" low="" optimum="50" high="90" max="100" value="70"></meter>

/* CSS */
/* vv Crucial, this will disable the default styling */
meter { -webkit-appearance: none; -moz-appearance: none; appearance:none; } 

meter::-webkit-meter-bar { /* Color of background */
    background: #acacac;
}
meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value { /* Color within low-high range */
    background: green;
}
meter::-webkit-meter-suboptimum-value { /* Color outside low-high range */
    background:red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SL7LH/1/) (specifically made for webkit)

If you actually want a gradient that goes from green to red you could use something like

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, lightgreen 0%, red 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, lightgreen 0%, red 100%);
```